# Why NOT to use Clean URLs?

Tags: uri

I have a theoretical question: why is there option to enable clean URLs? And I don't mean that they are not useful - on the contrary, I don't see the point of **not** using them. Why would anyone use URLs like `www.drupal.stackexchange.com/?q=questions/ask` if they can get rid of this `?q=`?

And why are they not at least a default option?

Comment: FYI this option has gone in Drupal 8: https://www.drupal.org/node/1659580

Comment: It is the default in Drupal 7. If your web-server supports URL rewriting, you'll get clean URLs by default.

Comment: Does that mean that Apache doesn't support them? Because it wasn't default for me and I'm using Drupal 7.

Comment: Some installs of Apache don't enable `mod_rewrite` by default, or allow hosts to use it.  Varies server to server.

Comment: Not sure why this warrants a downvote, it's an interesting question.  I have a theory that I will post as an answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My unconfirmed hypothesis is that this setting was still available through Drupal 7, even on servers that properly support rewrites, was to provide backward compatibility.

There are scenarios where you do something (upgrade from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7, move a site to a new server, etc) and want to retain your URL structure for SEO / ranking purposes.  In the case where you weren't able to use clean URLs on the old site, but can on the new site, means that you may not want to enable them.  You may also have the case where the un-clean URL is baked into body fields, so these URLs will still get out into the wild.

That said, there is little need for this given the state of contrib.  The [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) and [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) can handle inbound mapping with proper response codes so that search engines know the proper URL to update and serve back the updated one.  [Pathologic](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic) can rewrite old URLs on the fly to updated ones, to prevent the old URLs from getting out into the wild again.

Comment: Then why did they remove the option not to use Clean URLs in Drupal 8, as @Chapabu states? Redirect and Global Redirect were already there when Drupal 7 was released. Did they not handle inbound mapping yet on D7 release?

Comment: @user39042 I am not 100% sure (well, I don't recall).  This is the change record: https://www.drupal.org/node/1659580.   Some of it had to so with the change to use the Symfony based routing system, some of it was bringing Drupal 8 up to best practices.  I think my involvement in the routing system started after this decision was made (I don't recall working on any of this).

Answer (score 0):

There are web-servers not supporting url rewriting.

Comment: On Drupal 7, even if you have a server that support rewrites, you can still disable clean URLs.